# Found OpenFileDialog in Microsoft.Win32 but there is no OpenFolderDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

I have included using Microsoft.Win32 and when I type OpenFileDialog it finds the reference but there doesn't seem to be any OpenFolderDialog.  The Microsoft documentation says it exists but Visual Studio does not find it.  I am using WPF and VS2022. Is there some other alternative to selecting a folder instead of a file?  Thanks.

I tried to launch a new OpenFolderDialog and there is no reference to it in Microsoft.Win32.  I can use OpenFileDialog though.

Comment: You have two options: 1) Configure your project to use .NET 8 or later to enable the use of the brand new [OpenFolderDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfolderdialog?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) or 2) configure your WPF project to include WinForms libraries so that you can use the [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=windowsdesktop-8.0). The `FolderBrowserDialog ` is a native Win32 Windows control and not WinForms specific, so you it's perfectly fine to use it on any platform.

Comment: Thank you BionicCode.  I upgraded to .NET 8 and OpenFolderDialog was there.